# Validation Formula Help

Tags: lightning-experience, formula, validation-rule

Formula newbie question:

We currently have a validation rule when a record on a custom object is created, there are a list of fields that must be popluated. See below for the current formula:

```
(TEXT( Offer_Type__c ) = "Off-Platform" ) && (
ISBLANK( Off_Platform_Application__c) ||
ISBLANK( TEXT ( Offer_Type__c )) ||
ISBLANK( TEXT(Collection_Frequency__c )) ||
ISBLANK( TEXT( NF_Product__c ) ) ||
ISBLANK( Terms__c ) ||
ISBLANK( Max_Qualified_Line_Amount__c ) ||
ISBLANK( Rate__c ) )
```

I need to update it to where "Max_Qualified_Line_Amount__c" OR "Rate__c" must be populated. Can someone please help me with how this formula should be written?

Thanks!
Jenna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best practices for validation rules is to have *one rule* per field when possible. This allows you to add errors to specific fields, which helps users identify which fields need to be filled in to complete the form (including a red box around each field to fill in).

Aside from that, to check one of two options, you'd just add in AND (`&&`):

```
ISPICKVAL(Offer_Type__c, "Off-Platform") && (
    ISBLANK( Off_Platform_Application__c) ||
    ISBLANK( TEXT ( Offer_Type__c )) ||
    ISBLANK( TEXT(Collection_Frequency__c )) ||
    ISBLANK( TEXT( NF_Product__c ) ) ||
    ISBLANK( Terms__c ) ||
    (ISBLANK( Max_Qualified_Line_Amount__c ) && ISBLANK( Rate__c ) ) 
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!